# C# Get WCF error: ...target machine actively refused connection but only if the CLIENT runs as service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, service

At beginning I know there are many post to "actively refused connection" but i didn't found something to my spezial case.

We have a [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) self hosted `WCF-WebService` wich can be started as a real service or as a console application.

This service can call other of its kind to exchange files.

Now we have our first `Customer` where we need call the `(host)service` over a Proxy.

If I start the `(client)Service` as console application evrything works fine, but if run it as a service I got the Error:

```
Could not connect to http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:81/xxxxxxxxx/xml. 
TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively 
refused it xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:81.
```

The strange thing here is that I have the problem not with my authentication function (which works fine).

Sadly I have no idea whats going wrong here...

Thanks in advance

M.

Comment: Use tracing to find out what is going on. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Did you checked the log events to see if there was more info in there?

Comment: User permissions perhaps?